# Indentation of variable value with atom-beautify

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, atom-beautify

This is how I like to structure a variable block, especially if there are lots of variable definitions. In most cases the readability is better:

```js
var fooOpts     = config.get("mq.listener.options");
var fooDir      = config.get("mq.listener.workDir");
var fooTemplate = config.get("mq.listener.fileTemplate");
var fooQueue    = config.get("mq.listener.workerQueue");
var fooExchange = config.get("mq.listener.exchange");
var fooDone     = config.get("mq.listener.topics.done");
var fooError    = config.get("mq.listener.topics.error");
```

But when running `atom-beautify`, it jumps back to:

```
var fooOpts = config.get("mq.listener.options");
var fooDir = config.get("mq.listener.workDir");
var fooTemplate = config.get("mq.listener.fileTemplate");
var fooQueue = config.get("mq.listener.workerQueue");
var fooExchange = config.get("mq.listener.exchange");
var fooDone = config.get("mq.listener.topics.done");
var fooError = config.get("mq.listener.topics.error");
```

Is there a `.jsbeautifyrc` option to keep this kind of indention with atom-beautify or even to indent this automatically?